# Does sharing database structure make my application significantly more vulnerable?

Tags: database, security, database-design, client-server, desktop-application

I have a software that has two versions. One version is designed as a desktop application with its own database (MS SQL CE) that would reside on the user's machine. Another version has a client-server application where the database resides on a server. The database structure is nearly identical in both cases. The reason we have this setup is because we work in developing countries where the internet connection is unreliable and client-server or web-based applications are not always possible. Some of the software uses also don't require data-sharing and it's easier for the database to reside on the machine.

Someone with the desktop version can simply open up the SQL CE database and look at all of the tables and fields. Does this knowledge make my client-server application significantly more vulnerable to being hacked? If yes, what steps can I take to decrease the risk.

Answer (score 1):

Database structure by itself will not make your web application vulnerable. However if there is a SQL injection or other vulnerability somewhere in client-server application, for the attacker it would be much easier (will take less time) to operate with your database. 
In other words, your application is not less secure with exposed database structure, especially if it benefits performance for some users.

Answer (score 0):

Knowledge of the database structure can make your application less secure.

You can develop a frontend for your database structure so it is not directly exposed to the users.